# Cosmos inserts won't parallelize effectively

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

**Meta-Question:**
We're pulling data from EventHub, running some logic, and saving it off to cosmos.  Currently Cosmos inserts are our bottleneck. **How do we maximize our throughput?**

**Details**
We're trying to optimize our Cosmos throughput and there seems to be some contention in the SDK that makes parallel inserts only marginally faster than serial inserts.
We're logically doing:

```
            for (int i = 0; i < insertCount; i++)
            {
                taskList.Add(InsertCosmos(sdkContainerClient));
            }
            var parallelTimes = await Task.WhenAll(taskList);
```

Here's the results comparing serial inserts, parallel inserts, and "faking" an insert (with Task.Delay):

```
Serial took: 461ms for 20
 - Individual times 28,8,117,19,14,11,10,12,5,8,9,11,18,15,79,23,14,16,14,13

Cosmos Parallel
Parallel took: 231ms for 20
 - Individual times 17,15,23,39,45,52,72,74,80,91,96,98,108,117,123,128,139,146,147,145

Just Parallel (no cosmos)
Parallel took: 27ms for 20
 - Individual times 27,26,26,26,26,26,26,25,25,25,25,25,25,24,24,24,23,23,23,23
```

- Serial is obvious (just add each value)
- no cosmos (the last timing) is also obvious (just take the min time)
- **But parallel cosmos doesn't parallelize nearly as well**, indicating there's some contention.

We're running this on a VM in Azure (same datacenter as Cosmos), have enough RUs so aren't getting 429s, and using Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos 3.2.0.

Full Code Sample

```
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CosmosWriteTest().Wait();
        }

        public static async Task CosmosWriteTest()
        {
            var cosmosClient = new CosmosClient("todo", new CosmosClientOptions { ConnectionMode = ConnectionMode.Direct });
            var database = cosmosClient.GetDatabase("<ourcontainer>");
            var sdkContainerClient = database.GetContainer("<ourcontainer>");
            int insertCount = 25;
            //Warmup
            await sdkContainerClient.CreateItemAsync(new TestObject());

            //---Serially inserts into Cosmos---
            List<long> serialTimes = new List<long>();
            var serialTimer = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            Console.WriteLine("Cosmos Serial");
            for (int i = 0; i < insertCount; i++)
            {
                serialTimes.Add(await InsertCosmos(sdkContainerClient));
            }
            serialTimer.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine($"Serial took: {serialTimer.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms for {insertCount}");
            Console.WriteLine($" - Individual times {string.Join(",", serialTimes)}");

            //---Parallel inserts into Cosmos---
            Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "Cosmos Parallel");
            var parallelTimer = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            var taskList = new List<Task<long>>();
            for (int i = 0; i < insertCount; i++)
            {
                taskList.Add(InsertCosmos(sdkContainerClient));
            }
            var parallelTimes = await Task.WhenAll(taskList);

            parallelTimer.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine($"Parallel took: {parallelTimer.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms for {insertCount}");
            Console.WriteLine($" - Individual times {string.Join(",", parallelTimes)}");

            //---Testing parallelism minus cosmos---
            Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "Just Parallel (no cosmos)");
            var justParallelTimer = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            var noCosmosTaskList = new List<Task<long>>();
            for (int i = 0; i < insertCount; i++)
            {
                noCosmosTaskList.Add(InsertCosmos(sdkContainerClient, true));
            }
            var justParallelTimes = await Task.WhenAll(noCosmosTaskList);

            justParallelTimer.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine($"Parallel took: {justParallelTimer.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms for {insertCount}");
            Console.WriteLine($" - Individual times {string.Join(",", justParallelTimes)}");
        }

        //inserts 
        private static async Task<long> InsertCosmos(Container sdkContainerClient, bool justDelay = false)
        {
            var timer = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            if (!justDelay)
                await sdkContainerClient.CreateItemAsync(new TestObject());
            else
                await Task.Delay(20);

            timer.Stop();
            return timer.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        }

        //Test object to save to Cosmos
        public class TestObject
        {
            public string id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            public string pKey { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            public string Field1 { get; set; } = "Testing this field";
            public double Number { get; set; } = 12345;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you considered using SemephoreSlim?  It's lighter weight to set up than a full semephore.  probably too heavy for 20 items, I usually use it when I need to create > 10K queue messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the scenario for which Bulk is being introduced. Bulk mode is in preview at this moment and available in the [3.2.0-preview2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos/3.2.0-preview2) package.

What you need to do to take advantage of Bulk is turn the `AllowBulkExecution` flag on:

`new CosmosClient(endpoint, authKey, new CosmosClientOptions() { AllowBulkExecution = true } );`

This mode was made to benefit this scenario you describe, a list of concurrent operations that need throughput.

We have a sample project here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/tree/master/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Samples/Usage/BulkSupport

And we are still working on the official documentation, but the idea is that when concurrent operations are issued, instead of executing them as individual requests like you are seeing right now, the SDK will group them based on partition affinity and execute them as grouped (batch) operations, reducing the backend service calls and potentially increasing throughput between 50%-100% depending on the volume of operations. This mode will **consume more RU/s** as it is pushing a higher volume of operations per second than issuing the operations individually (so if you hit 429s it means the bottleneck is now on the provisioned RU/s).

```
var cosmosClient = new CosmosClient("todo", new CosmosClientOptions { AllowBulkExecution = true });
var database = cosmosClient.GetDatabase("<ourcontainer>");
var sdkContainerClient = database.GetContainer("<ourcontainer>");
//The more operations the better, just 25 might not yield a great difference vs non bulk
int insertCount = 10000;
//Don't do any warmup

List<Task> operations = new List<Tasks>();
var timer = Stopwatch.StartNew();
for (int i = 0; i < insertCount; i++)
{
    operations.Add(sdkContainerClient.CreateItemAsync(new TestObject()));
}

await Task.WhenAll(operations);
serialTimer.Stop();
```

**Important:** This is a feature that is still in preview. Since this is a mode optimized for throughput (not latency), any single individual operation you do, won't have a great operational latency.

If you want to optimize even further, and your data source lets you access Streams (avoid serialization), you can use the `CreateItemStream` SDK methods for even better throughput.

Comment: Thanks!  Do you have a preferred forum for feedback on this?  
One initial request is a mechanism to flush pending operations to Cosmos.  Ultimately some happy medium between "parallelizing single calls is slow" and "it's much faster but I have to send batches in the thousands"

Comment: Please provide any feedback to https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/issues

Comment: did this work?  Are you always writing 20 items?  For bigger inserts or writes, I usually use SemaphoreSlim.